# Keras CNN accuracy and loss are constant

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, resnet

I am building a keras CNN model using ResNet50 utilizing transfer learning. For some reason my accuracy and loss are exactly the same for every epoch. Strangely, I am seeing the same behavior with similar code but with VGG19. This leads me to believe that the issue is not with the actual model code and somewhere in the pre-processing. I have tried adjusting learning rates, changing optimizer, image resolution, freezing layers etc. and the scores do not change. I went into my image directories to check if my two different classes are mixed, and they are not. What is the issue? I just want to say thank you ahead of time.

P.S. I am training on ~2000 images and have two classes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from keras import optimizers

img_height, img_width, img_channel = 400, 400, 3 #change chanel to 1 instead of three since it is black and white

base_model = applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channel))

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(512, activation='relu',name='fc-1')(x)
#x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu',name='fc-2')(x)
#x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 2 classes
predictions = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

batch_size = 6

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        shear_range=0.1,
        zoom_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#possibely resize the image
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        "../Train/",
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=True
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        "../Test/",
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=True)

epochs = 10

history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2046 // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=512 // batch_size,
        callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('snapshots/ResNet50-transferlearning.model', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)])
```

This is the output given by keras:

```
Epoch 1/10
341/341 [==============================] - 59s 172ms/step - loss: 7.0517 - acc: 0.5577 - val_loss: 7.0334 - val_acc: 0.5588
Epoch 2/10
341/341 [==============================] - 57s 168ms/step - loss: 7.0517 - acc: 0.5577 - val_loss: 7.0334 - val_acc: 0.5588
Epoch 3/10
341/341 [==============================] - 56s 165ms/step - loss: 7.0517 - acc: 0.5577 - val_loss: 7.0334 - val_acc: 0.5588
Epoch 4/10
341/341 [==============================] - 57s 168ms/step - loss: 7.0517 - acc: 0.5577 - val_loss: 7.0334 - val_acc: 0.5588
Epoch 5/10
341/341 [==============================] - 57s 167ms/step - loss: 7.0517 - acc: 0.5577 - val_loss: 7.0334 - val_acc: 0.5588
```

Answer (score 1):

The final layer should have a 'sigmoid' activation instead of softmax since it is binary classification.

Comment: Your last Dense layer should have one unit per class, so predictions = Dense(**2**, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x). Having the softmax activation function is fine even for binary classification.

Answer (score 1):

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)
```

The Dense layer represents how many different classes are there which you want to classify and hence for binary classification you will require 2 where you have written 1.

So change that line to.

```
 predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)
```

Just a note, always try to keep a variable to handle number of classes, something like

```
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)
```

and then define num_classes at the start of your code for better flexibility and readability.

You can check documentation about Dense layer here : https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/2.0.0/layers/core/